# How to delete the millions of records from a db2 table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, zos

I am using DB2 9.7  for Z/oS. I have a table with 10+ million rows and I want to delete about 9 million rows. I have tried with below stored procedure, but without success.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETE_DATA 
(IN V_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(24), 
IN V_COMMIT_COUNT INTEGER, 
IN V_WHERE_CONDITION VARCHAR(1024))

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 01
COMMIT ON RETURN NO
LANGUAGE    SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC

L3 : BEGIN

-- DECLARE STATEMENTS
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER;
DECLARE V_DELETE_QUERY VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE V_DELETE_STATEMENT STATEMENT;

SET V_DELETE_QUERY = 'DELETE FROM ' || V_TABLE_NAME || 
' WHERE COLUMN IN (SELECT COLUMN FROM  ' 
|| V_TABLE_NAME ||  'WHERE COLUMN_ID =' 
|| V_WHERE_CONDITION  || ' FETCH FIRST ' 
|| RTRIM(CHAR(V_COMMIT_COUNT)) || ' ROWS ONLY) ';

PREPARE V_DELETE_STATEMENT FROM V_DELETE_QUERY;
DEL_LOOP:
    LOOP
        EXECUTE V_DELETE_STATEMENT;
        IF SQLCODE = 100 THEN
            LEAVE DEL_LOOP; 
        END IF;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END L3
```

Suggest me any changes in the above stored procedure.

Comment: If I would have been at your place then I would have inserted 1 million records which I dont want to delete in a seperate table and dropped the original table and rename the table having 1 million record to the original table name.(*Assuming it as a one time activity*)

Comment: I have to do this activity daily, before loading new data into table

Comment: That can sometimes be a bit too tricky, dependencies you know. (triggers, views, foreign keys etc.) (Answer to  Rahul Tripathi's comment.)

Comment: @jarlh:- Agreed, that's why I added at the last if its a *one time activity*.

Comment: Creating a new table in production platform is not that easy.

Comment: Instead of concatenating your parameters you should be using the `?` marker and `EXECUTE USING`... but the bigger issue I see is that you should be coding the delete explicitly for each table to purge.

Comment: There's no such thing as DB2 9.7 for z/OS. And what do you mean by "without success"?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205981/db2-stored-procedure-controlled-large-record-deletion/20470577#20470577

Comment: Have you checked the answer in that question. And do u think it works?

Comment: `FETCH FIRST ... ROWS` returns non-deterministic results in the case where you have no `ORDER BY`.  What exactly are you wanting to delete, yesterday's records?

Answer (score 2):

Extract the data that you wish to preserve, into a file suitable for input to sql loader utility.  Generate you new data, also to a file suitable for input to sql loader.   Truncate the destination table.   Run Sql loader using the two input files.  Clean, simple, repeatable, and it doesn't load up the log file.